# onmouseleave event fails after blur event

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, blur, mouseleave

I have an issue with a mouseleave event: When I first load the page, the mouseleave event works just fine but when I click on the searchBar(click event), then click outside (blur event), mouseleave stop working after the next hover(mouseover event) i.e the searchBar doesn't shrink (and the console does not print "leaving")

HTML code

```
<input type="text" id="searchBar" title="Chercher un projet" (mouseover)="handleHover()" (mouseleave)="handleLeave()" (click)="handleClick()" (blur)="handleBlur()" >
```

Typescript code

```
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {
  isFocused: boolean;
  constructor(public router: Router) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isFocused = false;
  }
  goTo(url: string) {
    this.router.navigate(['/' + url]);
  }
  handleLeave(){
    if(!this.isFocused) {
      $('#searchBar').stop(true, false);
      console.log("leaving");
      $('#searchBar').animate({width: 0}, 800);
    }
  }
  handleHover(){
    console.log("hovering");
    console.log($('#searchBar').is(':hover'));
    $('#searchBar').animate({width: 117}, 800);
  }
  handleClick(){
    this.isFocused = true;
  }
  handleBlur(){
    var s  = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("searchBar")).value;
    if(s === ""){
      $('#searchBar').stop(true, false);
      console.log("blurring")
      $('#searchBar').animate({width: 0}, 800);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `this.isFocused` back to false in the `handleBlur()` method.